# passing a massive array of 7500+ object for converting properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, require

I have an array object of length  7500+  that is returned in the success callback. I need to use a make use of a library to convert the properties northing and eastings from this object to lat and longs using a local library.. Does it make sense to make the call 7500 times in a for loop for getting new lat, longs and replace them in this object and  ultimately send to a map to plot pins ? 
Here' s my code:

```
var OSPoint = require('ospoint');
function getAllData() {
    function getPinsForAllSuccess(payload) {
        Ti.API.info('getpins : ' + JSON.stringify(payload)); 
       // 7500+ objects expected here
        for(var i=0; i < payload.length; i++){
            //Ti.API.info('easting: ' + payload[i].easting);                
            // Below is a call to the library to get lat longs
            var point = new OSPoint(payload[i].easting, payload[i].easting);
            var c = point.toWGS84(); 
            Ti.API.info('points: ' + JSON.stringify(c));                                
        }                                                            
    }

    function getPinsForAllError(err) {                
        Ti.API.info('getPinsForAllError: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }

  // Below is a service call method
    dbLib.getPinsForAll(getPinsForAllSuccess, getPinsForAllError, {
        site :  Alloy.CFG.loggedin_site
    });    
}
```

Comment: *"Does it make sense to make the call 7500 times in a for loop..."* As opposed to...what?

Comment: Unless the conversion is time-consuming or resource-consuming (for install, if it involves making a request to a server each time), there's nothing particularly challenging to the JavaScript engine about making 7500 function calls and doing some math in the function being called, if that's what you're asking. Function calls on modern (or frankly, even old) JavaScript engines are **very cheap**.

Comment: ("for instance", not "for install" -- guess what I was waiting for when I came to SO and saw your question? :-) )

Comment: My first question would be do you need all points? Can you not just call the function on the points when they are actually required? Plotting 7500 points, depending on zoom scale is going to be very cluttered unless you use clustering or some other mechanism